# Composer dependency within the same project in different modules

Tags: php, composer-php

My PHP project contains a base application and multiple modules. Each module can have a composer file requiring different libraries. The application holds some base libraries (also loaded trough composer). Now my problem.

The project has a payment functionality. Every module does support a payment gateway. I want to use omnipay (https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay) for my project. Omnypay comes with different gateways where each gateway can be loaded by itself trough composer like

```
{
    "require" : {
        "omnipay/paypal": "*"
    }
}
```

If I would put in each of the modules a composer.json file with a omnipay requirement, it would mean that the full omnipay stack (common, guzzle, simfony) is added to every payment gateway module. Now my question, is it somehow possible to use in my application composer.json file something like

```
{
    "config" : {
        "vendor-dir": "libraries/composer"
    },
    "require" : {
        "mustache/mustache": "*",
        "omnipay/common": "*"
    }
}
```

And then in the module a kind of dependency? Would an additional repository help? Something like the following composer.json file in my module?

```
    {
    "config" : {
        "vendor-dir": "libraries/composer"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../application/libraries/composer"
        }
    ],
    "require" : {
        "omnipay/paypal": "*"
    }
}
```

I tried that, but I don't know if this is the way to go. Additionally I get the error `Repository type is not registered: path` when I use the composer.json file from above.

I'm a beginner of composer, so please pardon if this is a trivial question. But I'm stuck right now.